# Decrement on While loops

Tags: java, loops, math

```
// Compute integer powers of 2.
class Power {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int e;
    int result;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      result = 1;
      e = i;

      while(e > 0) {
        result *= 2;
        e--;          // What is supposed to be decrementing and how???
      }

      System.out.println("2 to the " + i + 
                    " power is " + result);
    }
  }
}
```

Why is there a decrement on the while loop, but when running the program it give the impression as it is incrementing. Its very confusing to me please may somebody explain how operates this While loop?

> C:\Users\enrique\Desktop\Hello.java>java Power
>   2 to the 0 power is 1
>   2 to the 1 power is 2
>   2 to the 2 power is 4
>   2 to the 3 power is 8
>   2 to the 4 power is 16
>   2 to the 5 power is 32
>   2 to the 6 power is 64
>   2 to the 7 power is 128
>   2 to the 8 power is 256
>   2 to the 9 power is 512

Comment: ohh ok sorry. its my first time. thanks!

Comment: You are printing i which is incrementing  on each iteration.  e just controls how many times the 2 should be multiplied

Comment: Thanks i will try the different alternatives you have post.

Comment: Why not simply `result = 1 << i;`? Or, why not just initialize `result = 1` outside the loop, do nothing before the print statement, and double it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

`e` is the exponent and that while loop is doubling the value of the number until the exponent is less than or equal to 0.

It will remain the value of `i` unless it is decremented.

You could also convert it into a for loop like so

```
for (int e = i; e > 0; e--) { 
    result *= 2;
}
```

I understand if this is a learning exercise, but the `Math.pow` function could do the same thing.

Comment: It means that the while loop start looping from 9(backwards) and decrementing? also the while is squaring(power of two) not doubling. Thanks for aswering.

Comment: Only on the power of 9, yes

Comment: And, nope the number is doubling. You are multiplying by 2

Comment: its a practice, i had understand basic while loops, but this one behaves very differet to what i have come across.

Comment: The concept of the while loop hasn't changed. Loop until the condition isn't true...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same with an other int `j` which takes incremental steps to calculate `i-th` powers of `2`:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    result = 1;

    for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
        result *= 2;
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to use `while` inner loop:

```
int j = 0;
while(j < i){
    result *= 2;
    j++;
}
```

Comment: I know there are other way, but as im a newbie would like to understand this one first :)

Comment: In your code, as cricket_007 explained, `e` controls the number of times your `while` loop runs for each value of `i` to calculate exponent of `2` :)

Comment: Thanks i will try the different alternatives you have post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the while  loop you can use following simplified / efficient program.

```
int max=10, result=1, two=2;
for(int i=0; i<=max;i++)
{
 System.out.println(two + " pow " + i + " = " + result);
result*=two;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try the different alternatives you have post.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for the code you have In your question

```
Loop i from 0 to n
  Set result =1 
   Loop from 1 <= i
      result = result * 2 // multiply 2 the number of times equal to i
  Print result
End loop
```

Comment: Ok im understanding your explanation, what is left is, how e is incremented with an decrement operator? why a decrement operator seems to increment the variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Power {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  int e;
  int result;

 for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
      result =1 ;
      e = i;

      while(e > 0) {
          System.out.println(e); // not part of the original program 
          result *= 2 ;            
          e--;
          System.out.println(e); // not part of the original program           
      }

      // System.out.println("2 to the " + i +             
                      //" power is " + result);      

  }
 }
}
```

I figured out that by placing a `System.out.println(e)`, I could "see" the variable "e" behavior in order to make sense of the decrement. This is the output:

C:\Users\enrique\Desktop\Hello.java>`java Power: 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3`

`e = 1(iteration 1), 2^1, e (1) decremented to 0, e = 2 (iteration 2), 2^2, e(2) decremented to 1, e = 1 re-enter The while but is ignored as 2^1 is already registered, e (1) decremented to 0, e = 3 (iteration 3), 2^3…`